# How to make the event-driven consumer in Apache Camel delete the consumed messages?

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a rest service that sends messages to my queue, and these are routed to file:

```
from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").to("file://test");
```

Also, I have an event-driven consumer on the endpoint. For now this only writes to the log if a message is consumed:

```
final Consumer consumer = endpoint.createConsumer(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            String message = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

            LOG.info("Message processed: " + message);
        }
    });
```

This is all working fine. In the `/test` folder I am getting a new file for every message I recieve, and additionally the consumer creates a marker file appended with `.camelLock`. Using the `readLock=none` option prevents the consumer from making these marker files, as expected.

However, neither the message files nor the marker files are deleted after consumption. Am I perhaps missing something in my consumer implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here, as Claus Ibsen pointed out, was to done the UnitOfWork (UoW). Now my event-driven consumer looks like this:

```
final Consumer consumer = endpoint.createConsumer(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String message = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

        LOG.info("Message processed: " + message);

        ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();
        consumerTemplate.doneUoW(exchange);
    }
});
```

Also, the `delete=true` option must be used when creating the endpoint:

```
Endpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("file://test?delete=true");
```

Answer (score 4):

When you manually create a consumer like that with an inlined processor, you need to manually done the UoW of the Exchange when you are done to trigger work that would delete/move the file etc.

```
exchange.getUnitOfWork().done(exchange);
```

You can also try wrapping your processor with the `UnitOfWorkProducer` that should do the done of the UnitOfWork for you.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction - to manually done the UoW. I was not able to get your suggested approach to work however.

Instead I created a consumer template from the camel context, and manually done the UoW on this.

`consumerTemplate.doneUoW(exchange);`